# Invalid Parameter when creating a SpriteFont

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, spritefont

I am programming in C++ and am using the SpriteFont tools that comes with DirectXTK. I declared a variable in my class thus:

```
std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteFont> m_SpriteFont;
```

I initialized it like this:

```
m_SpriteFont = std::unique_ptr<SpriteFont>(new SpriteFont(m_d3dDevice.Get(), L"Assets\\TNR.spritefont"));
```

It gives an unhandled exception. Debugging through the program, it seems that there is a problem reading the file. The file is generated with the MakeSpriteFont.exe that comes with the toolkit. The font is Times New Roman, size 12. I have already added this file to the assets folder with Visual Studio Solution Explorer and the file itself is in the correct folder.

What is wrong here? Am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just so you know: that is assignment, not initialization. And you might as well just do `m_SpriteFont.reset(new SpriteFont(...))`.

Comment: It might be worth separating out the parts of the line to figure out which one is throwing the exception and let us know the details of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Something simple really, but I though I'd post it up here to remind everyone not to make the stupid mistakes I made.

When you add an existing item using the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, check it's properties and make sure it participates in the build (i.e. the Item Type flag is NOT set to "do not participate in the build"). I set the item type to "Font" and it worked.

Thank you everyone for the help.